# How to get complex64 output from numpy.fft?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have the following code:

```
Ga=rfft2(A)
```

`A` is type `float32`, but `Ga` comes out as `complex128` effectively doubling my data.  How can I get out `complex64` data? Certainly this isn't the default functionality for `fftw`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that the type is defined quite deep in the C code. [fftpack_litemodule.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/fft/fftpack_litemodule.c) uses `NPY_CDOUBLE` as the array type and that is basically your `complex128`. The only solution that I see is to transform the array to `complex64` using `astype(np.complex64)` or to use the [scipy.fftpack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html) package which returns an array of `float64` encoding the complex values as:

```
[y(0),Re(y(1)),Im(y(1)),...,Re(y(n/2))]              if n is even
[y(0),Re(y(1)),Im(y(1)),...,Re(y(n/2)),Im(y(n/2))]   if n is odd
```

Comment: I'm actually using `scipy.fftpack` and its returning `double` output for single `input`.